# Why do you wrap around in 16 bit checksum (hex used)?

Tags: numbers, hex, checksum

I have the question:

Compute the 16-bit checksum for the data block E3 4F 23 96 44 27 99 
F3. Then perform the verification calculation.

I can perform the addition and I get the overflow like:

> E3 4F
>   23 96
>   44 27
>   99 F3
>   ``````````
>   1 E4 FF (overflow)

The solution then takes the overflow and adds it causing E4 FF to become E5 00. Can someone explain to me why this occurs?

Comment: what would happen for larger data blocks if you never added the overflow?

Comment: @MartinSerrano In this case the sum of the bits is incorrect which will be the same when you have larger data blocks no? The only difference is in larger data blocks the sum will be even further off or am I mistaken on how this works?